# Fork()ing and running on specific set of CPUs

Tags: c, linux

I have a parent process, which I use to spawn a series of child processes, which each run their own program sequentially. Each of these programs change a file over time, I want to read the data from this file and see how it changes as each program runs.

I need two sets of data for this to work, the value of the file at some set interval (I haven't decided on the interval yet), and the time each program takes to run, there are other variables which can influence the execution times of these programs, which I want to see also.

So I figured to get more accurate timing of the child process while still reading from a file I could run them on different cores. I have 8 cores, I would like to run the parent process on 0-3, then fork the child to run on 4-7. I'm not sure if this is possible though within C, and a search around hasn't yielded any answers, which makes me think it isn't.

Within Linux, outside of a program, I can use `taskset` to do this.

I plan on setting aside 4 of the cores using the kernel parameter isolcpus(). I want as little noise as possible while running the child programs.

Comment: Did you take a look at the `sched_setaffinity()` function ? (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html)

Comment: XY problem. A typical Linux system has some 100 to 1000 processes times their threads. Your few threads will not make much difference, but might mess up your system even more. What is your actual problem? What do you mean with "accurate timing" here? (And don't just provide external links - a question has to be self-contained).

Comment: Why try this test in such a sterile condition that any results you obtain cannot be used to predict anything in the real world?

Comment: Surely, I'm going to get the same speedup/slowdown percentage no matter how sterile the environment. This way I'm just going to reduce the noise I get in any results. It's not a point I have considered before, so thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking the kernel to associate CPU cores with threads or processes is also known as setting the "affinity" between the core and the process/thread.

Under linux, there exists a set of functions that provide this capability.  Take a look at the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) for one of the functions...

```
man pthread_setaffinity_np
```

This family of API calls might be able to give you what you need.
That man page has a "see also" section that links to the other functions in this family.

Typically with features such as these that deal with kernel process and thread scheduling, it is entirely dependent on what mood the kernel is in at the time as to whether your requests are met or ignored.  Your mileage may very due to system load or the number of available cores.  Even if a system has 16 cores, these features may be disabled in the kernel compilation settings (think virtual machines).  Equally, you may find that there are some additional options that you may be able to add to your kernel to get better results than the defaults.